# What is this brltty init script?

Tags: init

I'm on my way to cleanup my system , started from init scripts , and found:

```
/etc/rcS.d/S25brltty
```

The description header wasn't helpful enough, and what's that used for, and if it's safe to purge ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The links in `/etc/rc?.d/` point to scripts in `/etc/init.d/`. As for `brltty`, it sounds like an accesibility feature for some Braille thing.

First, try to find out to which package it belongs:

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/init.d/brltty 
brltty: /etc/init.d/brltty
```

Well, that's clear, the `brltty` package is responsible for this. Let's get more information about it:

Excerpt from `apt-cache show brltty`:

```
Description-en: Access software for a blind person using a braille display
 BRLTTY is a daemon which provides access to the console (text mode)
 for a blind person using a braille display.  It drives the braille
 display and provides complete screen review functionality.
```

You can safely remove it, nothing really depends on it if you do not have a braille display (checked with `apt-cache rdepends brltty`)

Comment: apt-cache show is nice !

Answer (score 5):

Brltty enables braille accessibility for people with impaired vision. So yes, it's safe to remove if you're not blind or wear glasses!

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge brltty
```

If you don't need printing support you can also safely remove and purge cups-daemon.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge cups-daemon
```

To discover some more services and easily enable or disable them I installed bum (BootUp-Manager), a graphical tool for non-geeks.

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```