# Can not connect Arduino IDE with Arduino Board on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: connection, 22.04, arduino

I have freshly updated my Ubuntu 20.04 to the new 22.04 LTS release.
I have installed the Arduino IDE and add my user to the groups tty dialout uucp plugdevs.
When I connect my Arduino Nano per USB to my computer, in the Arduino IDE, the entry "Ports" of the menu "Tools" remains greyed out.
I've tried many different Arduino IDE, from the snap, from the website arduino.cc (the tarball 1.8.19 and the Appimage 2.0.0), and many different versions, nothing helps... I can not connect the IDE to the board. Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

This bug was mentioned in;

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brltty/+bug/874181

it is caused by the brltty daemon as mentioned. Another way is to disable it by;

```
systemctl stop brltty-udev.service
sudo systemctl mask brltty-udev.service
systemctl stop brltty.service
systemctl disable brltty.service
```

Answer (score 4):

```
sudo apt remove brltty
```

reboot the computer

...solved the problem (ports are now available and I can connect the Ardino IDE to the board).

Comment: Thanks for the post.  I was unsure if I could uninstall the item since I didn't know what it actually does, but this entry (https://askubuntu.com/questions/86635/what-is-this-brltty-init-script) explains what brltty is and can help you understand if you need it.