# Installed Arduino, cant find /dev/USB0 or /dev/ACM0

Tags: 22.04, arduino

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 and installed Arduino using

```
snap install arduino
```

which installed as expected.
I am aware I need to add my user to the dialout group, so I searched /dev for ttyACM* and also ttyUSB* using:
`sudo ls -al /dev/ttyUSB*` and `sudo ls -al /dev/ttyACM*` but got

`ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB*': No such file or directory`

and

`ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyACM*': No such file or directory`

I checked the ringbuffer for either of those using

```
sudo dmesg | grep tty
```

and got the following output:

```
[    0.167893] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[   86.158991] usb 2-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[   88.005204] usb 2-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[   88.006033] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1578.498248] usb 2-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1580.221903] usb 2-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 1580.223379] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
[ 1714.844660] usb 2-2: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now attached to ttyUSB0
[ 1716.573774] usb 2-2: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ftdi_sio while 'brltty' sets config #1
[ 1716.574710] ftdi_sio ttyUSB0: FTDI USB Serial Device converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
```

So ttyUSB0 does seem to be there.

It doesnt seem to be permissions (I think) since its not saying "Permission denied".

I also tried adding to the udev rules:
`sudoedit /etc/udev/rules.d/50-myusb.rules` and added the following lines:
`KERNEL=="ttyUSB[0-9]*",MODE="0666"`

`KERNEL=="ttyACM[0-9]*",MODE="0666"`

then saved and logged out and back in, but no change. I also tried rebooting, just to be sure.

I'm not sure how to proceed from here, can anyone please point me in the right direction?

Comment: In my case was the cable, after tried with 5 cables the fifth was the one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone else running into this same problem, here's what I found that worked for me.

After more searching I found [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1408192/can-not-connect-arduino-ide-with-arduino-board-on-ubuntu-22-04).

I removed brltty using the command:
`sudo apt remove brltty`
then rebooted.

After that when I ran:
`sudo dmesg -w`
and then plugged in the Arduino, I could see it and it was now able to be found under /dev/ttyUSB0.

Now I can program my Arduino!

Comment: For some more in-depth information, see: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670636/unable-to-use-usb-dongle-based-on-usb-serial-converter-chip